# Python - How to flatten JSON message in pandas/JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON message as below

```py
JSON_MSG = {
    'Header': {
        'Timestamp': '2020-10-25T02:49:25.489Z',
        'ID': '0422',
        'msgName': 'Order',
        'Source': 'OrderSys'
    },
    'CustomerOrderLine': [
        {
            **'Parameter'**: [
                {'ParameterID': 'ACTIVATION_DATE', 'ParameterValue': '2020-10-25'},
                {'ParameterID': 'CYCLES', 'ParameterValue': '1'}, 
                {'ParameterID': 'EXPIRY_PERIOD', 'ParameterValue': '30'},
                {'ParameterID': 'MAX_NUMBER', 'ParameterValue': '1'}
            ],
            'Subscription': {
                'Sub': '3020611',
                'LoanAcc': '',
                'CustomerAcc': '2020002',
                'SubscriptionCreatedDate': '2020-06-23T14:42:30Z',
                'BillingAcc': '40010101',
                'SubscriptionContractTerm': '12',
                'ServiceAcc': '11111',
                'SubscriptionStatus': 'Active'
            },
            'PaymentOpt': 'Upfront',
            'OneTimeAmt': '8.0',
            'RecurringAmt': '0.0'
            'BeneficiaryID': '',
            'CustomerOrderID': '111',
            'OrderLineCreatedDate': '2020-10-25T02:47:18Z',
            'ProductOfferingPriceId': 'PP_6GB_Booster',
            'ParentCustomerOrderLineID': '',
            'OrderLineRequestedDate': '2020-10-25T00:00:00.000Z',
            'ProductCategoryId': 'PRODUCT_OFFER',
            'OrderLinePurposeName': 'ADD',
            'OrderQuantity': '1.0',
            'CustomerOrderLineID': '11111',
            'OrderLineDeliveryAddress': {
                'OrderLineDeliveryPostCode': '',
                'OrderLineDeliveryTown': '',
                'OrderLineDeliveryCounty': '',
                'OrderLineDeliveryCountryName': ''
            },
            'ProductInstanceID': '95',
            'ProductOfferingId': 'OFF_6GBBOOST_MONTHLY'
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to flatten the JSON message and convert it into rows and capture the row count/record count

(or)

I need to find out how many elements are present under the nested array **Parameter**
as this would give me same result as that of flattened JSON(because **Parameter** is the innermost array)

So far i have tried the below code

```py
data = json.loads(JSON_MSG)
list1 = data['CustomerOrderLine']
rec_count = len(list1)
```

but this code gives the outer list's result only i.e. 1
as **CustomerOrderLine** contains only one structs

I need the record/row count as 4 (**Parameter** array has 4 structs)

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest one, but you could try something like:

```
list1 = JSON_MSG['CustomerOrderLine'][0]['Parameter']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get 'Parameter' sizes of all elements, you can use list comprehension:

```py
data = json.loads(JSON_MSG)
sizes = [len(order.get('Parameter')) for order in data.get('CustomerOrderLine', [])]
```